# user is true still not being redirected to the home page in react native expo go with Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, expo

I am creating the login system in react native expo go with firebase authentication, but for some reason when I signup it normally takes me to the `LoginSurvey` page which is fine, but when I login it just keeps me there on the login screen and did not take me to the `MainNaivgation`, I also check if that block of code is running or not where `MainNavigation` is mentioned by adding `console.log` which again runs fine, fine but only for some unknown reason it is not taking me to the `MainNavigation` even after `user` is registered and `user` is there

index.js

```
import MainNavigation from '../Navigation/MainNavigation';
import Registration from './Registration';
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { FIREBASE_AUTH, FIREBASE_DB } from '../firebaseConfig';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import { onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';
import { Context } from '../Context/Context';
import { doc, getDoc, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import LoaderAnimation from './LoaderAnimation';
import LoginSurvey from './LoginSurvey';


WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

export default function Index() {


  const { addUserData, state } = useContext(Context);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    checkLoggedIn();
    onAuthStateChanged(FIREBASE_AUTH, async (user) => {
      setLoading(false);
      if (user) {
        storeUser(user);
        setUser(user);
      }
    })
  }, []);

  const checkLoggedIn = async () => {
    const user = await getUser();
    if (user) {
      addUserData(user);
      setUser(user);
    }
  };

  const storeUser = async (user) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("@user", JSON.stringify(user));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error storing user data:", error);
    }
  };

  const getUser = async () => {
    try {
      const userString = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@user");
      if (userString) {
        const user = JSON.parse(userString);
        return user;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error retrieving user data:", error);
      return null;
    }
  };


  const TakeSurvey = async () => {
    const userRef = doc(FIREBASE_DB, 'users', state.userData.email);
    try {
      const docSnap = await getDoc(userRef);
      if (docSnap.exists()) {
        const userData = docSnap.data();
        const SurveyDone = userData['LoginSurveyTaken'];
        if (!SurveyDone) {
          return false;
        }
        else {
          return true;
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      {loading ? <LoaderAnimation height={'100%'} /> : user ? (TakeSurvey() ? (
        <>
          {console.log('it\' s coming till here')}
          <MainNavigation />
        </>
      ) : <LoginSurvey />) : <Registration />}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Where are you wrapping the code with the `Context.Provider`? Make sure that this `Index` component is a child of the `Context.Provider` otherwise the values from `useContext` won't work.

Also, you don't need to manually check async storage for the user in the `getUser` function, Firebase should do that for you automatically. 

Please post your whole code or link to the Github repo for more help.

Answer (score 0):

1st of all add console.log(''something to log ...') every where you think may caused this problem . then as i can see for now may be there is issue in the TakeSurvey to see that it is running correctly or not

```
const TakeSurvey = async () => {
  const userRef = doc(FIREBASE_DB, 'users', state.userData.email);
  try {
    const docSnap = await getDoc(userRef);
    if (docSnap.exists()) {
      const userData = docSnap.data();
      const SurveyDone = userData['LoginSurveyTaken'];
      if (!SurveyDone) {
        console.log('Survey not done');
        return false;
      } else {
        console.log('Survey done');
        return true;
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```